# Does the Jensen's inequality hold under expectation?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, jensen-inequality

In other words, does
$$
E\big[E[f(X)]\big] \ge E\big[f(E[X])\big]
$$
holds for a convex function $f(x)$?

If so why? or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Jensen, $E[f(X)] >= f(E[X])$. Therefore

$$E[E[f(X)]] = E[f(X)] ≥  f(E[X]) = E[f(E[X])$$

is true.

**Any true inequality holds under expectation.**

$A\geq B \Rightarrow E_X[A]=A\geq B=E_X[B]$